# if logic not working in array context for python

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have a function where depending on the type t a different function needs to be applied. I tried the following, but it does not work in a list context.

```
def compute(d, t='c'):
    """
    d is the computing variable
    t is the type, can be a list
    """
    if t == 'a':
        p = fa(d)
    elif t == 'b':
        p = fb(d)
    else:
        p = fc(d)
    return p
```

For instance, t could be

```
t = ['a', 'b', 'a' , 'c', 'b']
```

and should return

```
p = [fa(d), fb(d), fa(d), fc(d), fb(d)]
```

Any suggestions?

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: What is the expected outcome when `t` is a list?

Comment: with `t` as a list your function will always return the result of `fc(d)` - did you expect it to do something different ?

Comment: In you example above are you trying to call `compute` for each string in the list `t`?

Comment: yes, it should return a list where fa, fb, or fc is called depending on the value of t. t can be a scalar too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
def compute(d, t='c'):
    """
    d is the computing variable
    t is the type, can be a list
    """
    l = []
    for x in t:
        if t == 'a':
            l.append(fa(d))
        elif t == 'b':
            l.append(fb(d))
        else:
            l.append(fc(d))

    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[0]
    else:
        return l

compute(d, ['a', 'b', 'a' , 'c', 'b'])
```

It processes everything that is in `t`, be it a single item or a list.

Be aware that it returns the return values of the called functions, not the functions and their arguments